# Multicolored dashed line with a dashed pattern using QPen

Tags: c++, qt, qpen

I need to draw a multicoloured line with `QPen` that may consist of up to three colours within a dashed pattern.

Different colours should be on one line.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly draw it three times with different patterns so that the color of the first line shows through the gaps of the second and third, and the second color shows through the gaps of the third. It's hokey, but I think it could work depending on your actual needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developing the idea of [@goug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296497/multicolored-dashed-line-with-a-dashed-pattern-using-qpen/57305355#comment101090016_57296497), you can do something like:

```
void drawWithManualDashedLine(QPainter& painter, const QLine& line) {
  const int scale = 10;

  QPen pen;
  pen.setWidth(3);

  pen.setColor(Qt::red);
  pen.setDashPattern({ 0.0, 1.0 * scale, 1.0 * scale, 7.0 * scale });
  painter.setPen(pen);
  painter.drawLine(line);

  pen.setColor(Qt::green);
  pen.setDashPattern({ 0.0, 4.0 * scale, 1.0 * scale, 4.0 * scale});
  painter.setPen(pen);
  painter.drawLine(line);

  pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
  pen.setDashPattern({ 0.0, 7.0 * scale, 1.0 * scale, 1.0 *scale });
  painter.setPen(pen);
  painter.drawLine(line);    
}
```

Now, a more generic solution for `n` colors (I know it has too many parameters, it's just an idea). The trick is done creating a single dash-pattern, and *moving* it using [`QPen::setDashOffset`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#setDashOffset) for each color:

```
void drawMultiColorDashedLine(QPainter& painter, const QLine& line,
    int length, int gap, int width,
    const QList<QColor>& colors, bool startWithGap = false) {
  const int n = colors.count();
  const int initialGap = startWithGap ? gap : 0;

  QPen pen;
  pen.setWidth(width);
  pen.setDashPattern({ (qreal)length, (qreal)(gap * n + length * (n - 1)) });
  for (int ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii) {
    pen.setColor(colors[ii]);
    pen.setDashOffset(-ii * (length + gap) - initialGap);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawLine(line);
  }
}
```

So they can be called:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter painter(this);

  const QLine line1(0, height() / 3, width(), height() / 3);
  drawMultiColorDashedLine(painter, line1, 10, 20, 3, { Qt::blue, Qt::yellow }, true);

  const QLine line2(0, height() / 2, width(), height() / 2);
  drawWithManualDashedLine(painter, line2);

  const QLine line3(0, 2 * height() / 3, width(), 2 * height() / 3);
  drawMultiColorDashedLine(painter, line3, 10, 20, 3, { Qt::red, Qt::black, Qt::blue, Qt::magenta }, false);
}
```

[image]

The full working example is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/57296497-multicolored-dashed-line)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer and a working example! Much appreciated.